# Complex numbers using struct

Tags: c, struct, complex-numbers

I want to write a program that reads an array of complex numbers until 0+0j is entered and calculates the absolute value of these numbers and gives the maximum value.

1. i create a struct which includes im and re.
2. i take numbers from user and check it whether it is equal to 0+0j
3. i send the inputs array to absc function
4. in absc function i created a new array which is equal to sqrt(re^2+im^2) and i send this new array to another function find_max
5. in find_max i find the max value of absolute array.
6. Then i print the max value.

However, i fail and i don't understand where should correct.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#define SIZE 5

struct stComplex
{
    int re, im; 
}; 

typedef struct stComplex Complex; 

float absc(float[]);
float find_max(float[]);

int main()
{
    Complex inputs[SIZE]; //Array for inputs

    int i;
    float max;

    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++
        printf("Enter real part of complex number: ");
        scanf("%d", &inputs[i].re);
        printf("Enter imaginary part of complex number: ");
        scanf("%d", &inputs[i].im);

        if(inputs[i].re != 0 and inputs[i].im != 0)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }   
    }

    max = absc(Complex inputs[SIZE]); //Sending the real and imaginary parts to calculate absolute value

    printf("The biggest absolute value is %f", max);

    return 0;
}

float absc(Complex x[SIZE]) 
{
    int i;
    float absolute[SIZE], max; 
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        absolute[i] = sqrt(pow(inputs[i].re, 2) + pow(inputs[i].im, 2));
    }
    max = find_max(absolute[SIZE]); 

    return max; 
}

float find_max( float array[SIZE] )
{
    int i, max;
    max = array[0];
    for( i = 1; i < SIZE; i++ ) 
    {
        if( max < array[ i ] )
            max = array[ i ];
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: This looks more like C than C++, so I removed the C++ tag. Also, can't you use the new C `complex` types for this?

Comment: "*However, i fail*".  **How?**  What are your inputs, expected output, and actual output?

Comment: i have to make it with structs

Comment: `max = absc(Complex inputs[SIZE]);` does this compile?  `for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++` certainly does not compile.  `float absc(float[]);
float absc(Complex x[SIZE]) {
` are in conflict.

Comment: Unless you are restricted, please change to `double` asap. Otherwise `float` is a-l-m-o-s-t 19th century.

Comment: @templatetypedef: Which tag is appropriate depends on the compiler used. We should check with the OP before removing tags.

Comment: I take imputs from user, my expected output is the largest absolute value and my actual output is an error " [Error] cannot convert 'float' to 'float*' for argument '1' to 'float find_max(float*)' "

Comment: I am baffled as to why `struct stComplex` has `int` types for real and imag components.

Comment: @chux yes actually i have an error over there

Comment: Note: OP "fail" is a series of compilation failures (at least 4).  OP could at least identify the lines that fail.

Comment: ... even more baffled as to why you use `pow` to square a number.

Comment: Simplification: `absolute[i] = sqrt(pow(inputs[i].re, 2) + pow(inputs[i].im, 2));` --> `absolute[i] = hypot(inputs[i].re, inputs[i].im);`

Comment: Did u try max = find_max(absolute);

Comment: `find_max(absolute[SIZE]);` does not pass the array to the function as you expect, but passes array element at position `SIZE`.

Comment: @WeatherVane i am not an expert, i've been learning c for 2 months.

Comment: @chux thank you so much

Comment: Also try using max = absc(inputs);

Comment: @MustafaCanerSezer neither am I, the comments were only intended to be helpful criticisms.

Comment: @Abhi thank you it helped a lot

Comment: @MustafaCanerSezer please check the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#define SIZE 5

struct stComplex
{
    int re, im; 
}; 

typedef struct stComplex Complex; 

float absc(Complex inputs[]);
float find_max(float[]);

int main()
{
    Complex inputs[SIZE]; //Array for inputs

    int i;
    float max;

    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter real part of complex number: ");
        scanf("%d", &inputs[i].re);
        printf("Enter imaginary part of complex number: ");
        scanf("%d", &inputs[i].im);

        if(inputs[i].re != 0 && inputs[i].im != 0)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }   
    }

    max = absc(inputs); //Sending the real and imaginary parts to calculate absolute value

    printf("The biggest absolute value is %f", max);

    return 0;
}

float absc(Complex inputs[SIZE]) 
{
    int i;
    float absolute[SIZE], max; 
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        absolute[i] = sqrt(pow(inputs[i].re, 2) + pow(inputs[i].im, 2));
    }
    max = find_max(absolute); 

    return max; 
}

float find_max( float array[SIZE] )
{
    int i, max;
    max = array[0];
    for( i = 1; i < SIZE; i++ ) 
    {
        if( max < array[ i ] )
            max = array[ i ];
    }
    return max;
}
```